# CSV reader incorrectly parses tabspaces after inverted commas

Tags: python, csv, double-quotes, csvreader

I am using the CSV reader to read a TSV in Python. The code is:

```
f = csv.reader(open('sample.csv'), delimiter='\t')
for chunk in f:
   print(chunk)
```

One row from the tab separated CSV file looks like this (csv hosted [here](https://github.com/erzaliator/RadomDump/blob/main/sample.csv)):

| doc | unit1_toks | unit2_toks | unit1_txt1 | unit2_txt2 | s1_toks | s2_toks | unit1_sent | unit2_sent | dir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GUM_bio_galois | 156-160 | 161-170 | " We zouden dan voorstellen | dat de auteur al zijn werk zou moeten publiceren | 107-182 | 107-182 | Poisson declared Galois ' work " incomprehensible " , declaring that " [ Galois ' ] argument is not sufficient . " [ 16 ] | Poisson declared Galois ' work " incomprehensible " , declaring that " [ Galois ' ] argument would then suggest that the author should publish the opinion . " [ 16 ] | 1>2 |

I am getting the following output (the CSV reader is missing some tab spaces):

```
['GUM_bio_galois', 
'156-160', 
'161-170', 
' We zouden dan voorstellen\tdat de auteur al zijn werk zou moeten publiceren\t107-182\t107-182\tPoisson declared Galois \' work  incomprehensible " , declaring that " [ Galois \' ] argument is not sufficient . " [ 16 ]', 
'Poisson declared Galois \' work " incomprehensible " , declaring that " [ Galois \' ] argument would then suggest that the author should publish the opinion . " [ 16 ]', 
'1>2']
```

I want it to look like this:

```
['GUM_bio_galois', 
'156-160', 
'161-170', 
'" We zouden dan voorstellen',
'dat de auteur al zijn werk zou moeten publiceren',
'107-182',
'107-182',
'Poisson declared Galois \' work  incomprehensible " , declaring that " [ Galois \' ] argument is not sufficient . " [ 16 ]', 
'Poisson declared Galois \' work " incomprehensible " , declaring that " [ Galois \' ] argument would then suggest that the author should publish the opinion . " [ 16 ]', 
'1>2']
```

How can I get the CSV reader to handle incomplete quotes and retain them in my output?

Comment: Can you post the actual `repr()` of the header and one line so that we don't need to reconstruct it ourselves?

Comment: Note that the fact it uses quotes suggest there are fields that have delimited inside it and that's why they have to use quotes. Of course there is always possibility the csv file was not constructed properly in the first place

Comment: Try using `open('sample.csv', encoding='utf8')`.

Comment: @martineau using `open('sample.csv', encoding='utf8')` has no effect.

Comment: @buran I have provided a link to the csv (header included) hosted on github. Also adding in the comment again: [here](https://github.com/erzaliator/RadomDump/blob/main/sample.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('sample.csv') as f:
   rdr = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='\t')
   header = next(rdr)
   for line in rdr:
      print(line)
```

or using `csv.DictReader`:

```
import csv
with open('sample.csv') as f:
   rdr = csv.DictReader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='\t')
   for line in rdr:
      print(line)
```

Comment: I would like to write the same to another file. I am again running into an issue with the quotes. I tried `writer = csv.writer(open('target.csv', 'w'), delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` and then `writer.writerow(line)` but I get this error: `_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set`

Comment: @Someone: The error is because you need to define `escapechar=` to "a one-character string used by the writer to escape the *delimiter* if *quoting* is set to `QUOTE_NONE`", to something. Note that after doing so, you'll also need to define it when reading the file later. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar).

Comment: @martineau I don't want to add any escapechars (need to keep the file in original state). I have found this way to work: `writer = csv.writer(open('target.csv', 'w'), delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')`

Comment: @Someone: I was just quoting you the documentation which explains the `_csv.Error` you were getting. BTW, in Python 3, CSV files should always be opened with a `newline=""` option — again, read the fine docs.